# If I click on Radio button, name must be change

Tags: html, radio-button

How to do if I click on radio button, name must be change. Example, if I click on Issue radio button, Security Name but be change to Recipient or if I click on Return radio button, Security Name must be change to "Return by". And I have no idea how to make it. Is there a way to do that?

```
<div class="col-sm-8 radio" style="margin-left: 60px;">
    <p class="form-control-static" style="display: inline-flex;white-space: break-spaces;">
        <label><input type="radio" name="status" onclick="check(this.value)" value="issue" ><b>Issue</b></label>
        <br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="status" onclick="check(this.value)" value="returnn" ><b>Return</b></label>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Second code is for Showing Security Name.

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="badgeid" style="margin-left: -50px;">Security Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secuname" name="secuname" placeholder="Enter Name" value="<?php echo $securityname; ?>">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
  <br>
```

Comment: well, for that you will need to use javascript to show the input that is relevant to the radio selected

Comment: How to do? Can you please show me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here Is Your Answer(last code section)

```
<div class="col-sm-8 radio" style="margin-left: 60px;">
    <p class="form-control-static" style="display: inline-flex;white-space: break-spaces;">
    <label><input type="radio" name="status" onclick="check(this.value)" value="issue" ><b>Issue</b></label>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="status" onclick="check(this.value)" value="returnn" ><b>Return</b></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

---

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="badgeid" style="margin-left: -50px;">Security Name:</label>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secuname" name="secuname" placeholder="Enter Name" value="<?php echo $securityname; ?>">
      </p>
</div>
```

---

That's your code, now the JS you wanted in comments to do change an input's name based on another radio button input

## is here

---

```
var statusRadioButtons = document.getElementsByName('status');
var specialInput = document.querySelector('#secuname') ;
statusRadioButtons.forEach( item => item.addEventListener("change",handleChangeName)) 
function handleChangeName(ev) {
    var value = ev.target.value;
    if( value == "issue" ) {
         specialInput.setAttribute('name','receipt') ;
    } else if ( value == "returnn" ) { 
         specialInput.setAttribute('name','returnBy') ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where should I put that JS Sir? above the Issue and Return codes?

Comment: because it's selecting your input elements, it should be after them, if you place it above them js can't find your elements (because they do not exist YET), best place for scripts is at the bottom of your page, right before ```</body>```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the change event on the radios :

```js
let radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="status"]');
radios.forEach(radio => {

    radio.addEventListener('change', (radio) => {
       let value = radio.value
       // hide all irrelevant inputs
       let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.depend-on-radio-status');
       divs.forEach(div => {
           divs.style.display = 'none';
       })
       // show relevant input
       let div = document.querySelector('div.depend-on-radio-status.value-' + value);
       div.style.display = 'block'
    })
});
```

```
// set the default value here in the style
<div class="depend-on-radio-status value-issue" style="display:block">
// your issue input / label
<div>
<div class="depend-on-radio-status value-return" style="display:none">
// your return input / label
</div>
```